# How to make Mysql and windows IIS server time in same format

Tags: c#, asp.net, mysql, datetime

I am having problem in querying mysql using time.

```
DateTime dt = DateTime.Now;
string datet = dt.ToString("yyyy-MM-dd hh:mm:ss"); //gives 2013-04-17 12:59:31
```

but at the same time when i query sql using-->

```
SELECT NOW()
```

it gives 2013-04-17 00:59:24

my following query fails when hour component is 12 am(24 hrs)

The query i am using is

```
 string q = "SELECT orderid,fname,subtotal FROM userinfo WHERE dtbook > '" + from + "' AND dtbook < '" + to + "'
```

when i run the following query in sql changing 12 to 00

```
SELECT * FROM userinfo WHERE dtbook > CAST('2013-04-17 00:00:00' AS DATETIME)
```

I get correct result but since i have to calculate time from server the query to database
my query becomes

```
SELECT * FROM userinfo WHERE dtbook > CAST('2013-04-17 12:00:00' AS DATETIME)
```

I have tried both on server to converttime
ToString("yyyy-MM-dd h:mm:ss") and ToString("yyyy-MM-dd hh:mm:ss") but result are the same
 how can i get hour component in 00 when it is 24 hours??

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Well, the *immediate* problem is that you're using `hh` instead of `HH`. `hh` is the specifier for a 12-hour value; `HH` is the specifier for a 24-hour value.

However, you should *not* be converting the date into a string in the first place. Instead of converting the value into a string and including it as part of your SQL statement, you should use a parameterized query, and set the parameter to the value *as a `DateTime`*.

That way:

- You avoid the CAST in your SQL
- You avoid the problematic string conversion
- The code will be clearer (you'll be able to see your SQL with no string concatenation involved, and you're separating the code from the data)
- You'll get in the habit of writing parameterized queries

You should *always* parameterize your SQL - primarily to avoid [SQL injection attacks](http://bobby-tables.com) but also for all the benefits above. More generally, avoid conversions when they're unnecessary - every conversion has the potential for going wrong.

Comment: hh is the specifier for a 12-hour value; HH is the specifier for a 24-hour value. thankx for the answer, I was really confused what was wrong. I will keep in mind the point specified by you .

Comment: Please *don't* just bear it in mind. Fix your code to use parameterized queries as a matter of urgency. It really is extremely important - and easy to do.